# What is the correct way of using forcing term in BVP definition

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am giving a simplified example of a code I am trying to implement

```py
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import numpy as np
p = [1, 2]
a = 0.5
num = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 1, num)

var = np.ones((1, int(num/2)))
for i in range(int(num/2)):
    var[0, i] = i**2


def fun(x, y):
    force = np.zeros_like(x)
    force[x <= 1-a] = -((np.polyval(p, y[0]))[x <= 1-a])*np.interp(x, x, var)

    return np.vstack((y[1], y[2], y[3], force))


def bc(ya, yb):
    return np.array([ya[0], ya[1], yb[0]-1, yb[2]])


y_guess = 0*np.ones((4, x.size))
res = solve_bvp(fun,bc,x,y_guess)
```

I am facing the following error

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

I would also like to clarify that I have made up the var matrix as x^2 and want to use `np.interp` function to use in the forcing term of the actual fourth order BVP that I am trying to solve. My forcing term is discontinuous, being given by the polyval function for x in (0,0.5) and zero otherwise. Removing the interp function makes the code work, but I am not able to find the correct way of including this term.

Comment: What is the BVP for this example?

Comment: @jared the BVP is $y''''= -f(y)var(x)$, where f(y) is zero when $x>a$

Comment: With f(y) being the polyval? And where is the forcing term in that?

Comment: @jared Yes correct. I am calling the whole of f(y)*var(x) as the forcing term as in the term which appears on the RHS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your error first, `interp` takes three arguments: `x`, `xp`, and `fp`. `xp` and `fp` are the x and y values that you know, and they should be 1D arrays with a one-to-one correspondence. Currently, `var` is of shape `(1,50)`, which is not 1D, hence the "too deep" error. You can fix that and change it to `var.ravel()`, but then you get the error that the shapes don't match since `x.shape = (100,)` and `var.ravel().shape = (50,)`.

Either way, I would change your code to have separate function to handle `f(y)` and `var(x)`. Now, `f(y)` isn't actually correct because it is actually a function of x and y, i.e. `f=f(x,y)` (since `f(x>a,y) = 0`). For simplicity, I'll also refer to `var(x)` as `g(x)` (`vars` is a python keyword so I avoid `var` since it's close). You'll want the ODE to call the two functions, so you can make them arguments and use `functools.partial` to deal with `solve_bvp` expecting a function of only x and y.

For `f(x,y)`, I used `np.polynomial.Polynomial` to create the polynomial and call it (note: this class takes the coefficients in the opposite order of `np.polyval`, hence the reversing). I then update the points where `x > a` to be 0.

For `g(x)`, I just used the `x**2` form that you mentioned, but you can change this to your needs. Though, because `g(x)` is only a function of x and x is constant (you set these values), `g(x)` (or any function of x) is constant and doesn't actually require a function.

Below is the `solve_bvp` code I would use, though `sol.success` is `False`, which is probably a consequence of this problem being made up and not having any valid solution.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
from functools import partial

p = [1., 2.]
poly = np.polynomial.Polynomial(p[::-1])
a = 0.5
num = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 1, num)

def g(x):
    return x**2

def f(x, y):
    res = poly(y)
    res[x > a] = 0.
    return res

def ode_full(x, y, f, g):
    yp1 = y[1]
    yp2 = y[2]
    yp3 = y[3]
    yp4 = -f(x, y[0])*g(x)
    
    return np.vstack([yp1, yp2, yp3, yp4])


def bc(ya, yb):
    return np.array([ya[0], ya[1], yb[0]-1, yb[2]])


y_guess = np.ones((4, x.size))

ode = partial(ode_full, f=f, g=g)
sol = solve_bvp(ode, bc, x, y_guess)
print(sol.success)
```

Comment: This was very informative and solved the problem for me. Thank you.